# systemd service failed to start with errror : "main process exited, code=exited, status=3/NOTIMPLEMENTED"

Tags: linux, redhat-enterprise-linux, systemd, upstart, init-script

I am getting below error when i start a systemd service

```
[localhost.localdomain]-> systemctl status rcc_rccproxy.service 
* rcc_rccproxy.service - starts RCC Proxy process
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/rcc_rccproxy.service; enabled; vendor 
preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2009-03-25 21:46:27 CDT; 
12min ago
  Process: 7597 ExecStart=/var/RCC/rccproxy.sh (code=exited, status=3)
 Main PID: 7597 (code=exited, status=3)

Mar 25 21:46:27 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Started starts RCC Proxy 
process.
Mar 25 21:46:27 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Starting starts RCC Proxy 
process...
Mar 25 21:46:27 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: rcc_rccproxy.service: main 
process exited, code=exited, status=3/NOTIMPLEMENTED
Mar 25 21:46:27 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Unit rcc_rccproxy.service 
entered failed state.
Mar 25 21:46:27 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: rcc_rccproxy.service 
failed.
```

what is the reason for this? what do the status error indicating?

Basically this service is starting a shell script. If i run the same script manually, dont see any errors.

Journalctl logs for this PID doesn't show up anything either as well.

Comment: The question of why something runs from the CLI and not under systemd is an FAQ. Pleas see: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/339645/20239

Answer (score 0):

> > If i run the same script manually, dont see any errors

Most probably, Exit code 3 is emitted by your shell script. If you execute the shell script and then do "$?", If this results "3" - Then you should add 3 to your success status codes.